# Passing symbols inside Json through HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, symbols

I try to pass message to MS Flow in Json format, using following method, but once I pass any symbols (like ") I get an error as symbols are recognized as code.

```
public static bool notification(string customer, string comment)
    {
        try
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("my msflow link goes here");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{ \"customer\":\"" + customer + "\",\"comment\":\"" + comment + "\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: it's a bad idea to create your JSON by hand like this - it's prone to silly syntax errors, and problems with the interpretation of certain characters, as you've discovered. Instead create a C# object and then serialise it using something like [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). That way the serialiser will take care of any special characters inside your data and escape/encode them appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize your objekt in the code like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(<your object>);
```